# Python [ mod_wsgi ] works via cli but not via apache

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

cli:

```
[root@localhost 0]# python test13.wsgi
(1, 'aaaaaa')
[root@localhost 0]#
```

apache:

> Internal Server Error

full script code:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "root",
                        passwd = "",
                        db = "aaa")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("select * from bbb limit 1")
row = cursor.fetchone ()
print row
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    return row
```

error_log:

```
[Fri May 10 16:04:07 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3692): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri May 10 16:04:20 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3691): Create interpreter 'localhost.localdomain|/0'.
[Fri May 10 16:04:20 2013] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3691, process='', application='localhost.localdomain|/0'): Loading WSGI script '/0/test13.wsgi'.
[Fri May 10 16:04:20 2013] [error] (1, 'aaaaaa')
[Fri May 10 16:04:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3691): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/0/test13.wsgi'.
[Fri May 10 16:04:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type int found
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is breaking it.

Comment: is it suppose to be in a [] ? my other hello world examples have..  `return [output]`

Comment: The first element in `row` is an integer. `return [repr(row)]` should work.

Comment: so, how can i select this comment as "answered" . ? it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application` should return an iterable of strings. Yours returns a tuple (which is an iterable) of an integer and a string, which won't work:

```
TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type int found
```

Change that `return` line to:

```
return [repr(row)]
```